# RegEx Perl syntax to Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match jpeg images in HTTP GET requests.

For example in :

```
GET /category/catpic.jpg HTTP/1.1
```

the Regex should return : `catpic`

I managed to get a RegEx in Perl syntax that works fine :

```
/(?<=\/)[^(\/)]+(?=(\.jpg HTTP))/g
```

but I just don't know enough about Python to convert it to Perl syntax.

- Can anyone help me convert this Perl RegEx in a Python RegEx ?

Thank you in advance !

EDIT: Sorry, I explained it wrong. I want to match ANY .jpg image in a HTTP GET request.

Comment: It's the same regex, just a different programming approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put what's between the slashes in Perl into a raw string `r"(?<=\/)[^(\/)]+(?=(\.jpg HTTP))"` and pass it to the appropriate function in the `re` module.

Comment: Thank you a lot ! I will mark the question as answered in 2 min.

Answer (score 0):

use this regex `(?<=category/)(.+?)(?=\.jpg HTTP)`

Comment: This doesn't do the same thing as the Perl regexp. Why are you looking for `category` specifically?